# reverse engeeneering the 3d file of a game

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, file-format

I have a problem to find out how to open a file of a game this one seems to have encrypted its files.

[image]

Currently all I know about the file is that it seems to be a custom 3D file.

here is the file link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tfuHEVhMt9ZdQlI3UeXXHuehy_UAhvrb

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reverse engineer the code, which works with this file, in order to understand which was the encryption algorithm. There's no way to guess it from the data in Hex editor.

Comment: it is a client of an old game where I have already found some info about the extension but no more since it is a proprietary format to the game engine.

I'm going to keep digging around a little longer.